# Is there a way to figure out the size of a program's canvas using c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm fairly new to c++ and was wondering if there is a way to figure out the canvas' size of another program?

For example, code something that will tell me the size and position of a program like Task Manager or CommandPropmt. Of course, they would have to be opened first.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question).

Comment: And that's why I came here.

Comment: Get Petzolds book and read it

Comment: The point of me asking is so that I don't have to read a whole book that might or might not even answer my question. I thought that was the point of stackoverflow.

Comment: Not really. You aren't going to get anywhere by asking a question every time you need to learn something. How will you know what to ask? Read Petzold and learn from the group up. Don't imagine that you can become an expert in a couple of weeks without doing the basic legwork.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but people learn differently. Maybe this is my way of learning. I have programming books which I have not read. Why? Because I don't see what I want to learn and get bored half way through them. And I end up here. All the time. Even though I don't want to ask questions because people like you decide to leave negative comments instead of helping.

Comment: @David This might be good advice if the Petzold book were any good.

Comment: Your opinion differs fro mine Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to do this - get the window handle with FindWindow(), and then get the size of the window using GetWindowRect() or GetClientRect(), depending on which bit of the application window you want the size of. All these functions are part of the Win32 API and are [fully documented online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you, I will check those out!